# oracle 11g express edition - restore username and password

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I restore a username and password for the Oracle database?

I have try:

```
C:\Users\sa>orapwd file=PWDXE.ORA password=new_sys_password entries=10
```

I copied the file to a location `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database`

```
C:\Users\sa>set oracle_sid=xe

C:\Users\sa>sqlplus sys/new_sys_password as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Feb 26 13:57:05 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
```

sqlnet.ora

```
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
#sqlnet.authentication_services = (NONE)
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)
names.default_domain = world
name.default_zone = world
automatic_ipc = off
```

listener.ora

```
# LISTENER.ORA Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = COMP1A862)(PORT = 1521))
      )
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )
```

And tnsnames.ora

```
# TNSNAMES.ORA Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\ora92\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
XE.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =COMP1A862)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

What I'm doing wrong?

p.s.
services are running
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the password and you are ON the server machine you can (assuming you set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID env variables) do:

sqlplus / as sysdba

You can then unlock or change the password of any user - e.g. to change password:

alter user  identified by ;